# JS function with bug

Tags: javascript, html

The following code should display an alert with inputs values, but it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/srLnys9d/))

```js
function greetings(greeting, name) {
  var Greeter = function(greeting, name) {
    namer.onName(function(name) {
      this.greet(name);
    });

    this.greet = function(name) {
      window.alert(greeting + ', ' + name + '!');
    };
  };

  var Namer = function() {
    var callback;

    this.onName = function(cb) {
      callback = cb;
    };

    this.tellName = function(name) {
      callback(name);
    };
  };

  var namer = new Namer();
  var greeter = new Greeter(greeting, name);
  namer.tellName(name);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Something:
  <input id="greeting" type="text" value="Bye!" />SomeName:
  <input id="name" type="text" value="Jack" />
  <input type="button" value="Greet!" onclick="greetings(document.getElementById('greeting').value, document.getElementById('name').value)" />
</p>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.greet is not a function` - there's why.

Comment: Generally speaking, when working with Javascript it is a good idea to keep the console open. (i.e. right click and inspect element --> console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `this` from `this.greet(name)` and replace `this.greet = function(name)` with `function greet(name)`.

```js
namer.onName(function(name) {
  greet(name);
});

function greet(name) {
  window.alert(greeting + ', ' + name + '!');
};
```

```js
function greetings(greeting, name) {
  var Greeter = function(greeting, name) {
    namer.onName(function(name) {
      greet(name);
    });

    function greet(name) {
      window.alert(greeting + ', ' + name + '!');
    };
  };

  var Namer = function() {
    var callback;

    this.onName = function(cb) {
      callback = cb;
    };

    this.tellName = function(name) {
      callback(name);
    };
  };

  var namer = new Namer();
  var greeter = new Greeter(greeting, name);
  namer.tellName(name);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Something:
  <input id="greeting" type="text" value="Bye!" />SomeName:
  <input id="name" type="text" value="Jack" />
  <input type="button" value="Greet!" onclick="greetings(document.getElementById('greeting').value, document.getElementById('name').value)" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this anonymous function:

```
function(name) {
   this.greet(name);
}
```

is not bound to Greeter context.
So at the time it is called here:

```
this.tellName = function(name) {
  callback(name);
};
```

`this` points to `Namer` object which doesn't have `greet` method, so `this.greet is not a function` error is produced.